# SQL count results in groups, with repeating groups

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, gaps-and-islands, group

I have this data:

```
ARRIVAL,ITEM_TYPE,ITEM
1,0,Cat
2,0,Dog
3,1,Horse
4,1,Cow
5,0,Fish
6,0,Barn
7,0,Potato
```

I would like to query for this result:

```
0,2
1,2
0,3
```

... showing that in order by ARRIVAL there was a group of 2 items with ITEM_TYPE = 0, then 2 with ITEM_TYPE = 1, then **another** group with ITEM_TYPE = 0.  The goal is to provide information about the arrival in a system of similar groups of records; Cat and Dog are in the same ITEM_TYPE as Fish, Barn, and Potato, but they didn't arrive in the same time-series group. I can't figure out how to use COUNT,DISTINCT,and GROUP BY in a way that doesn't collapse the two groups of zeroes into a single line like this:

```
0,5
```

I will appreciate any help.

-- Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *gaps and islands* problem here, you could use the difference between two row_numbers approach to solving it :

```
SELECT ITEM_TYPE, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM (
  SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ARRIVAL)
          - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_TYPE ORDER BY ARRIVAL) AS grp
  FROM mytable
) t
GROUP BY grp, ITEM_TYPE
ORDER BY ARRIVAL;
```

Results :

```
ITEM_TYPE   CNT
0           2
1           2
0           3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mH53D3vQ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This is working successfully on my data; I am now studying OVER and PARTITION in order to understand why it works.

Comment: I want to make sure that I understand what's going on here, including the performance questions:

Comment: I want to make sure that I understand what's going on here, particularly wrt to performance:
The first OVER clause is finding the row number in a full query result sorted by arrival.
The second OVER, with a partition, is finding the row number in each partition, for a differently sorted temporary result set (sorted by ITEM_TYPE and then ARRIVAL).  This must have some performance effect.
The two OVER clauses, subtracted, provide a repeating value inside each group, which is used by COUNT(*)

Am I correct about that separate sort + performance?

Comment: both row_number() will create a sequential numbering for rows and then using the difference between these row numbers will help identify and group consecutive values,  The outer query then groups the data by this calculated grp together with  ITEM_TYPE to identify islands of consecutive numbers. It uses COUNT() to get count of each island. have a look here for more examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands

Answer (score 1):

We should use window function as below:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ARRIVAL INT, ITEM_TYPE INT,ITEM VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO  mytable(ARRIVAL, ITEM_TYPE,ITEM)
VALUES
  (1,0,'Cat'),
  (2,0,'Dog'),
  (3,1,'Horse'), 
  (4,1,'Cow' ),  
  (5,0,'Fish'),
  (6,0,'Barn'),
  (7,0,'Potato');


WITH cte as (
    SELECT ARRIVAL, ITEM_TYPE,ITEM
    , CASE WHEN ITEM_TYPE = (lag ( ITEM_TYPE) OVER ( ORDER BY ARRIVAL ) ) OR (lag ( ITEM_TYPE) OVER ( ORDER BY ARRIVAL ) ) IS NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END check_lag
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT MIN(ITEM_TYPE) ITEM_TYPE, COUNT(1) 
FROM (
    SELECT ARRIVAL, ITEM_TYPE,ITEM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ARRIVAL)  
      - SUM(check_lag) OVER(ORDER BY ARRIVAL ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grp
    FROM cte
) sub
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I understand what you're doing with LAG, but for my application it doesn't appear to be necessary to answer my question specifically.  As it happens, some of the grouping in my application is in pairs, and LAG may work for me to filter the first and second pairs in those groups.  I appreciate the lesson.