# count of sequences in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

example input table:

| id | date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-1-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-1-2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2020-1-3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2020-1-4 | 0 |
| 5 | 2020-1-5 | 0 |
| 6 | 2020-1-6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2020-1-7 | 0 |
| 8 | 2020-1-8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2020-1-9 | 1 |

output table:

| start_date | end_date | status | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-1-1 | 2020-1-3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-1-4 | 2020-1-5 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-1-6 | 2020-1-6 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-1-7 | 2020-1-7 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-1-8 | 2020-1-9 | 1 | 2 |

my database: sqlite3

Thank you very much for your help

I tried a lot to solve this problem with chatbots, but the queries they gave were not working properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called gaps and islands problem. Inspired by [SQL count results in groups, with repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641457/sql-count-results-in-groups-with-repeating-groups), you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INT,
    date DATE,
    flag BOOL
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
(1, '2020-1-1', 1),
(2, '2020-1-2', 1),
(3, '2020-1-3', 1),
(4, '2020-1-4', 0),
(5, '2020-1-5', 0),
(6, '2020-1-6', 1),
(7, '2020-1-7', 0),
(8, '2020-1-8', 1),
(9, '2020-1-9', 1);

SELECT MIN(date) AS start_date, MAX(date) AS end_date, flag AS status, COUNT(*) AS length
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY id) AS grp
    FROM t
)
GROUP BY grp, flag
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: If I have a column that is the user ID and I want to calculate this for each user, how will it happen?

Comment: You have to partition first ROW_NUMBER by iduser and second by iduser, flag